# Make more than one run able file while exporting project eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have create a selenium test in eclipse java. There are two classes. Now I want to export project as jar and want to run two different classes.
But when I run java -jar myProject.jar

it run only one class that I have select as Launch configuration.

but I want to run another class that in jar.

java -jar myProject.jar testClass2

how to export jar file to achieve this.

Comment: not sure what your situation is, but you could look into running jars with command-line arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runable java files have a single main class. You will need to create an instance of your second class from the Main method of the start-up class.

Comment: but these have different tasks

Comment: If they are completely different, then it would make sense to have two separate projects with their own .jar's.

Comment: You can however use start up parameters, which will allow you to start either class by changing the command line args: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html